# GIT: Managing Multiple Platforms

Tags: git, repository

I am working on mobile apps and we have 1 repository per project. Every project may be developed for multiple platforms, like Android and iOS. What we have now is a sub-directory for each platform in the root directory of GIT repository. For some reason I think it's not a good practice. What do people usually do in such cases? What is the most common solution? So far I know only three options: separate branches, repositories and as it is.

Comment: What's your concern about keeping different platforms in different subdirectories?

Comment: Firstly, you must download stuff you are never going to use. Secondly, you see commit messages even though it's useless for you. In other words - making everything cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use [Git sub modules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules). You can have a multiple 'sub-projects' inside a project.